# How can I set the style width of a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, signalr

I have a twitter bootstrap progress bar which is defined like this:

```
<div style='position: relative' class='progress progress-info'>
    <div class='bar' id='signalRtensionNegPercentage-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #' style='display: block; float: right; width: 15%'>
    </div>
    <span class='gridSpan' id='signalRtensionNeg-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #'>#: TensionNegative#</span>
</div>
```

The `#: ... #` part is a dynamic id handled by SignalR and Kendo-UI. In my SignalR script I set the percentage width like this:

```
messageHub.client.notifyTension = function (tensionMessage, conveyanceId) {
    var maxTensionRange = $('#signalRmaxTensionRange-' + conveyanceId).text();
    var minTensionRange = -maxTensionRange;

    var tensionPos = $('#signalRtensionPos-' + conveyanceId).text();
    var tensionNeg = $('#signalRtensionNeg-' + conveyanceId).text();

    var percentageValPos;
    var percentageValNeg;

    if (maxTensionRange != 0 && minTensionRange != 0) {
        if (tensionMessage < 0) {
            percentageValNeg = Math.abs((tensionNeg / (maxTensionRange - minTensionRange)) * 100);
            $('#signalRtensionNegPercentage-' + conveyanceId).width(percentageValNeg);
            $('#signalRtensionNeg-' + conveyanceId).text(tensionMessage);
        } else {
            percentageValPos = Math.abs((tensionPos / (maxTensionRange - minTensionRange)) * 100);
            $('#signalRtensionPosPercentage-' + conveyanceId).width(percentageValPos);
            $('#signalRtensionPos-' + conveyanceId).text(tensionMessage);
        }
    }
};
```

My issue here is that the entire bar appears to be expanding, and not the blue filler (progress-bar). I'm guessing it is because is set the `$('#signalRtensionNegPercentage-' + conveyanceId).width(percentageValNeg);` part. Anyone know how I can set the style: width property as I'm supposed to in order to define the percentage width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one .

```
$('#somediv').width('70%');
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Here is just syntax:

```
$("#yourdiv").css("width", "300px");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be a percentage value. Can I do something like this:
$("#yourdiv").css("width", percentageParameter+"%");

Comment: $("#yourdiv").css("width", "300%"); for static.